# Add filename to formset for display purpose only

Tags: django

I have a model which contains a number of user uploaded files that other than the file itself also contain a description and some other meta information.

```
class ArchiveFile(models.Model):
    archive_file = models.FileField(upload_to=grab_archive_folder, default=None, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

What I want is for a user to (1) upload new files. And (2) be able to edit the descriptions of all files associated with the user, including the recently uploaded. The uploading of new files is done via AJAX / JQuery and new forms (as part of a formset) are generated dynamically.

In order to do be able to edit the descriptions in an efficient matter, it would help for a user to know of what file it is changing the description, and so I would like the filename to be displayed.

My initial solution was the following:

forms.py

```
class ArchiveDataForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['archive_file'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True

    class Meta:
        model = ArchiveFile
        fields = ['archive_file','description']
```

views

```
def archive_data_update(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':

        ArchiveDataFormSet=modelformset_factory(ArchiveFile, form=ArchiveDataForm, extra=0)
        archive_formset = ArchiveDataFormSet(queryset=ArchiveFile.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)

        template = 'archive_data_edit.html'
        template_context = {
            'archive_formset': archive_formset,
            ...
        }

        return render(request, template, template_context)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        ArchiveDataFormSet=modelformset_factory(ArchiveFile, form=ArchiveDataForm, extra=0)
        archive_formset = ArchiveDataFormSet(request.POST, queryset=ArchiveFile.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)

        if archive_formset.is_valid():

            for archive_form in archive_formset:

                archive_form.save()

            return HttpRespone('ok')
```

template

```
{% for archive_form in archive_formset %}
    {{ archive_form.archive_file.value }}
    {{ archive_form.description }}
{% endfor %}
```

My issue is that I am getting validation errors on the dynamically created forms, saying that no file is present. Which I suppose is correct since all I do is inject the filename to the dynamically created form via my AJAX/JQuery. Is there a way I can ignore this validation for the purpose of this form only? or is there an easier/different way to display the filenames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments:

- If you **only** want to edit the descriptions you should **not** include as a form field the `archive_file` field.
- You could instead pass in your view the instance of the form to the context of the request. And then interpolate the title of the file in the template.

If you could provide your view code, we can discuss an actual implementation.

UPDATE:

Looking at the source code of model form, you hava always available the instance of the object of the form. why don't you try using that?

As in:

```
# template
{% for archive_form in archive_formset %}
    {{ archive_form.instance.archive_file.filename }}
    {{ archive_form.description }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have added the relevant views code. The code is taken from a much larger method, the rest of which is not relevant as far as I can tell and has been left out for readability. If you feel you are missing something let me know. Also your approach sounds like exactly what I want, but I don't know how to go about implementing it.

Comment: I never knew you could access the actual object from a form object, neat-o. One small issue, it works when I use {{ archive_form.instance.archive_file }}, but the .filename attribute returns None. Not entirely sure what attributes exist but .url and .path seem to work.